# Measure the network traffic on a long-term basis

Tags: internet, traffic, measure

I'd like to find out how much network traffic my computer uses, i.e. whether a limit of 30GB of transfer wouldn't be too little. What's the best tool to measure it?

Using Linux Mint 17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vnstat is a CLI option.  vnstat can run as a daemon that can be queried from CLI.

```
apt-get install -y vnstat # install the software
vnstat -u -i eth0 # enable monitoring of eth0 by default
service vnstat restart # this may not work on Mint, I don't have a system to test with, but it does work on CentOS
vnstat -h # show per-hour breakdown of traffic for the past 24 hours
```